# Get Ancestors tree view against specific child id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table for task with name tbl_tasks . This have data and also have parent_id.

Structure of table is

```
    t_id, project_id, title ,          parent_id
      1       1         Task1               0
data  2       1         Sub Task1           1
      3       1         Child Sub task1     2
```

And there is another table with name tbl_sharedtasks in this table have data of shared task.

Structure of table is

```
    project_id,user_id,t_id,createdby

data  1          1       3      3
```

When I want to show a Ancestors tree view for my shared task this detect only one record but not detect its parent record. which should 1 and 2 also because shared t_id 3 have pareint_id 2 and 2 have pareint_id 1

This is my code

```
  $qry="SELECT sh.task_id,tsk.* FROM tbl_sharedtasks sh,tbl_tasks tsk where sh.project_id=1 and sh.user_id=1 and tsk.t_id=sh.task_id";
                        $result=mysql_query($qry);
                        $arrayCategories2 = array();

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
                        $arrayCategories2[$row['t_id']] = array("parent_id" => $row['parent_id'], "title" =>                       
                        $row['title'],"task_id" => $row['t_id']);   
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
                        {
                        ?>
                        <?php 

                        createTreeView($arrayCategories2, 0); ?>
                        <?php
                        }?>
```

This is my CreateTreeView Funciton

```
function createTreeView($array, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1) 
{
$id=0;
foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category) 
{
    $id++;

    if ($currentParent == $category['parent_id']) 
    {                       
        if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo " <ul style='list-style:none; cursor:pointer' id='folder21'> "; 

        if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li> ";

        echo "<li > <span class='file'>&nbsp;";?><a onClick="selecttaskval('<?php echo    $category['task_id'];?>','<?php echo $category['title'];?>');"><?php echo $category['title'];?></a> </span>
        <?php
        if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) { $prevLevel = $currLevel; }

        $currLevel++; 

        createTreeView ($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);

        $currLevel--;               
    }   

 }

 if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li>  </ul> ";

 }
```

This is working fine only when I select records from tbl_tasks but not when I want to detect it from my shared table.
Please help with thanks

Comment: Would some sort of 'tree' processing be useful for this? maybe useful: [7162873/category-hierarchy-from-arraycat-id-parent-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162873/category-hierarchy-from-arraycat-id-parent-id/27169144#27169144). Also: [27360813/php-convert-array-to-multidimensional-array-by-parent-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360813/php-convert-array-to-multidimensional-array-by-parent-id/27377770#27377770). Also it would be useful if there was an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with test data.

Comment: What kind of tree...?

Comment: This is ul base tasks tree. tasks have parent and I want to select all Ancestors against specific sub task id